# C++ data packing from uchar to int (both positive and negative numbers)

Tags: c++, opencv, int

I have a OpenCV Mat of type CV_32S with contains integer values of >= -1.
I am trying to access the underlying [data pointer](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4d33bed1c850265370d2af0ff02e1564) which is a flat 1D array of type `uchar`.

I suppose that since `int` is 4 byte [32 bits] and `uchar` is 1 byte [8 bits] I need to unpack the data into int type which is initially provided in a OpenCV Mat structure.

```
cv::Mat opencv_data;  //! data of type CV_32 with both negative and positive values.
```

I pass the `uchar *data` pointer of `opencv_data` to cuda kernel. 
To unpack the four `uchars` into single `int` I doing the following.

```
int value =   (uchar)opencv_data[index] |
            (((uchar)opencv_data[index + 1]) << 8) |
            (((uchar)opencv_data[index + 2]) << 16);
```

When the opencv_data has only positive values I get the correct unpack value in `value`. However if I put a single negative number in `opencv_data` the above unpacking produces `value = -1`.

I fail to understand the reason behind this problem and I need help with this.

**EDIT:** based on suggestion to use `reinterpret_cast`. The update code is below but for negative numbers the result is still not correct.

```
//! for test only    
cv::Mat test = cv::Mat(40, 60, CV_32S);

for (int j = 0; j < test.rows; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < test.cols; i++) {
        test.at<int>(j, i) = -2;
    }
}

int INDICES_BYTE = test.step * test.rows;
uchar *data = reinterpret_cast<uchar*>(test.data);
for (int i = 0; i < INDICES_BYTE; i += 4) {
    int index = reinterpret_cast<uchar>(data[i]) |
                (reinterpret_cast<uchar>(data[i + 1]) << 8) |
                (reinterpret_cast<uchar>(data[i + 2]) << 16) |
                (reinterpret_cast<uchar>(data[i + 3]) << 32);
    std::cout << index  << "\n";
}
```

The edited code produces correct result for positive number but not for negative numbers in `test`.

Eg: for -2 the result is *16777215*

Comment: If you want a signed integer, why are you using `unsigned char`?

Comment: Since opencv stores the data as uchar. I think from here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4d33bed1c850265370d2af0ff02e1564

Comment: Ah woops, brainfart... I don't have a real solution for you but maybe you can debug it using a `union` to extract the individual bytes? Just take a number and try to work out which byte should get which value. Also maybe the endianness of the storage in the `cv::Mat` is different, so that the signed bit gets assigned the wrong?

Comment: Surely you can use `reinterpret_cast` for this?

Comment: @talonmies I changed the code to use reinterpret_cast and when I use negative number I get large bits like eg. -2 -> 16777215. I updated ur suggestion above.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding how this works. Within a CV_32S format matrix, the data is *stored* as signed integers, In a pitched linear memory allocation whose pointer is stored as a pointer unsigned char.

Comment: I don't know how opencv works, but you've misused `reinterpret_cast`. It has no effect in your code. Also, overflowing an `int` with `<<` is undefined behavior, thus you should cast array values to `unsigned int` (or even better `uint32_t`) and then shift them. Also, `data[i+3]` should be shifted by 24 bits, not 32.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for you spot on the 32 which was suppose to be 24. A silly mistake. Besides once I changed 32 to 24 I can get the results without changing uchar to int type. I understand what you explained but I am confused since  I have 4 uchars from which I want a int so thats why I cast it to uchar. I would really appreciate if you can explain this again. Thanks

Comment: @talonmies thanks for your clarification. Perhaps I think i am in wrong track at the moment!!! Do you mean that uchar pointer is a pointer to the int pointer? If so, then how do I copy the ints pointed by uchar pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that there are a few concepts you have misunderstood here.

The openCV `mat` stores the address of the memory allocation which holds the matrix data in a `uchar *`. This doesn't mean that the data is in any way transformed. If you want to access the data associated with the matrix directly, you simply cast the pointer to the correct type and use that cast pointer. Like this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat test = cv::Mat(4, 6, CV_32S);
    for (int j = 0; j < test.rows; j++) {
       for (int i = 0; i < test.cols; i++) {
          test.at<int>(j, i) = -2*i;
       }
    }

    int *p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(test.data);
    for(int j=0; j<test.rows; ++j) {
        for(int i=0; i<test.cols; ++i) {
            std::cout << j << "," << i << " = " << p[i] << std::endl;
        }
        p += test.cols;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This gives correct result and thanks for rectifying my mistakes. All this while i was mistaken about the OpenCV mat representation.

Comment: You can simply use: `int *p = test.ptr<int>();`

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped the last shift, it should be:

```
(reinterpret_cast<uchar>(data[i + 3]) << 24);
```

Note that this method invokes undefined behavior if the last shift overflows, but for most current implementations, it should not cause a problem. Btw, you do not need the `reinterpret_cast<uchar>` since `data` is an array of `uchar`. Here is a safer method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < INDICES_BYTE; i += 4) {
    unsigned u32 = data[i] | (data[i + 1] << 8) | (data[i + 2] << 16) |
                   ((unsigned)data[i + 3] << 24);
    int index = (u32 <= INT_MAX) ? u32 : ~(int)~u32;
    std::cout << index << "\n";
}
```

Note still that this method makes assumptions about the byte ordering of integer types. A much simpler approach is to consider `test.data` as pointing to a simple array of `int` with `int *p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(test.data);` as posted in **talomies**' answer.

Finally, all these methods assume that the 2D array is packed, ie: `test.step == test.cols * sizeof(int)`, which may not be guaranteed.

Comment: Why even have `reinterpret_cast` if `data` is `uchar *`?

Comment: Thanks actually this was a mistake in my code ie. the 32 was suppose to be 24. I tried and your correction code works well. Your explaination of the shifting and overflows is nice.  However, I accepted @talonmines answer as it provide direct solution to the problem i faced with OpenCV structure.